# Reverse Event Order in Month View

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Basically, if I have this:

```
events: [
    {
    title: 'First',
    start: new Date(2014, 1, 24, 8),
    end: new Date(2014, 2, 3, 8)
},
{
    title: 'Second',
    start: new Date(2014, 2, 3, 8),
    end: new Date(2014, 2, 10, 8)
}
]
```

The First event displays below the Second Event.
Because this is a continuation of an event from the week above, I would like the First event to display above the Second event.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: Could you add what code you currently have so we can see what you're using and have tried to use before?

Comment: I was able to recreate this in the demo included with 1.6.4, just edit the Default.html so the events equal this.